# Increment, Decrement, and clear with buttons kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm a beginner so please excuse the simplistic question.  I'm trying to create a control screen that displays a count.  Essentially I want it to get a low signal on one of the GPIO's and advance one integer.  I also want the ability to edit the count with "+", "-", and "clear" buttons.  This is one of the first bits of code I've ever written so I may be way off base here! Here is the code for the .py:

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

startPin = 17

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(startPin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

class InputButton(Button):
    def update(self, dt):
        if GPIO.input(startPin) == True:
        self.ids.textbox.text +=1

class MainWidget(FloatLayout):

    def adv_callback(self, text):
        self.ids.textbox.text += 1

    def fall_callback(self, text):
        self.ids.textbox.text -= 1

    def clear_callback(self, text):
        self.ids.textbox.text = 0


class MainApp(App):
    '''docstring for MainApp'''
    def build(self):
        return MainWidget()


if __name__=="__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

and the .kv

```
# File name main.py

<MainWidget>:

canvas.before:
    Color:
        rgba: .95, .95, 1, .7
    Rectangle:
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size
Button:
    id: clear
    text: 'Clear'
    font_size: '50sp'
    pos: (650, 0)
    size_hint: .2, .3
    on_press: root.clear_callback(self.text) 

Button:
    id: add
    text: '+'
    font_size: '50sp'
    pos: (0, 142)
    size_hint: .2, .3
    on_press: root.adv_callback(self.text)

Button:
    id: less
    text: '-'
    font_size: '50sp'
    pos: (0, 0)
    size_hint: .2, .3
    on_press: root.fall_callback(self.text)

AsyncImage:
    source: '/home/sysop/Pictures/Source_Files_Pocono_logo_on_White_Bg.gif'
    size_hint: .5, .3
    pos: (200, 285)

TextInput:
    id: textbox
    multiline: False
    readonly: True
    size_hint: .5, .3
    font_size: '80sp'
    pos: (325, 0)

ActionBar:
    pos: (0, 432)
    ActionView:
        ActionPrevious:
            title: ""
            with_previous: False
        ActionOverflow:
            ActionButton:
                text: "Shutdown"
                on_press: app.open_settings()
```

Comment: And what's wrong with what you have now?

Comment: It looks to me like you're concatenating strings instead of increasing values. Can you try?
`self.ids.textbox.text = str(int(self.ids.textbox.text) + 1)`

Also, it would be useful if you wrote what is your current output and how it differs from your wanted output.

Comment: It would be much easier if you tied everything to a `NumericProperty` on your root widget.  You could then increment, decrement, and display it entirely in kv.

Comment: This code displays the screen ok but once you push any of the buttons it closes the program and flags an error. My wife is having a baby tomorrow so I won't be able to try anything until early next week.

Comment: How would I tie everything to a NumericProperty?

Comment: @Doom8890   This worked! Thank you so much!